useEffect that fetches supabase data on mount breaks when I refresh the page, and loops infinitely when I add any dependency
When the first mount happens, everything works fine, but when I refresh the page (and only when I refresh the page) I get this error.

VM7552 page.tsx:40 Error fetching data:
{code: 'PGRST301', details: null, hint: null, message: 'JWSError (CompactDecodeError Invalid number of parts: Expected 3 parts; got 1)'}
code
:
"PGRST301"
details
:
null
hint
:
null
message
:
"JWSError (CompactDecodeError Invalid number of parts: Expected 3 parts; got 1)"

If I don't use useEffect, and just create a button that fetches on click, everything works fine, and when added a dependency (it didn't matter what dependency I added) they all had the same problem, which was making the useEffect loop infinitely
/profile/[id]
export default function Profile() {
  const { getEntries, deleteEntry } = useEntries();
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState<Entry[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchEntries() {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const fetchedEntries = await getEntries();
        setEntries(fetchedEntries);
        console.log(entries);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchEntries();
  }, []);

// rest of the code

/api/entries.ts
import { useClerkSupabaseClient } from "@/services/supabase";
import { AddEntryProps } from "@/types";
import { useAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export function useEntries() {
  const { userId } = useAuth();
  const supabase = useClerkSupabaseClient();

  if (!supabase) {
    throw new Error("Supabase client is not initialized");
  }

  async function addEntry({ prompt, entry }: AddEntryProps) {
    if (!userId) {
      throw new Error("User ID is missing, cannot add entry");
    }

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("Entries")
      .insert([{ prompt, entry, user_id: userId }])
      .select();

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting Entry:", error.message || error);
      throw error;
    }

    return data;
  }

  async function getEntries() {
    if (!userId) {
      throw new Error("User ID is missing, cannot fetch entries");
    }

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("Entries")
      .select("*")
      .eq("user_id", userId);

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error getting Entry:", error.message || error);
      throw error;
    }

    return data;
  }
// rest of the code

/services/supabase.ts
import { useSession } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { createClient, SupabaseClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { useMemo } from "react";

//? Supabase client instance
let supabase: SupabaseClient | null = null;

export function useClerkSupabaseClient() {
  const { session } = useSession();

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!supabase) {
      //? Create the Supabase client instance if it doesn't exist
      supabase = createClient(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY!,
        {
          global: {
            fetch: async (url, options = {}) => {
              //? Get Clerk token
              const clerkToken = await session?.getToken({
                template: "supabase",
              });

              const headers = new Headers(options?.headers);
              headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${clerkToken}`);

              return fetch(url, {
                ...options,
                headers,
              });
            },
          },
        }
      );
    }
    //? Return the singleton Supabase client
    return supabase;
  }, [session]);
}


